# Android: How to get WebView working?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I am trying to create a `WebView` in my android app and I have the **imports** as follows:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

I have added the **uses-permission** as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And I have this as my **onCreate():**

```
    private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

}
```

I am still unable to get it to work as I am getting `Cannot Resolve Method` errors on the Following:

```
setWebViewClient
getSettings()
setOverScrollMode
loadUrl
```

and `Cannot Resolve Symbol` on the following:

```
R.id.webView
OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
```

Any help anyone please?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".WebView">


<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    /> 

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:onClick="Home"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/WebView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you changed package name etc. recently?

Comment: Please post your layout  (xml) file

Comment: Added it there and yeah the package is right

Answer (score 0):

You defined your own Java class named `WebView`, one that is serving as your `Activity`. As a result, the compiler is having difficulty distinguishing between your own `WebView` and `android.webkit.WebView`. This covers most of your problems.

The exception is the symbol-not-found error for `R.id.webView`. You are getting that because your layout has `android:id="@+id/webview"`. Most things in Android are case-sensitive, and that includes widget IDs. I recommend going with lowercase `webview` in both places.

Comment: so what do I change exactly in relation to the Javaclass?

Comment: also once I change `R.id.webView` to `R.id.webview` it comes up with this error: `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'fyp.com.pastec_currency_recognition.WebView'`

Comment: I created another activity named `Browser_Web_View` and copied all of it in and changed the necessary areas and it fixed the bulk of the issues, so i think that solved what you meant, only issue is as mentioned in the previous comment about `R.id.webView` to `R.id.webview`

Answer (score 0):

**JavaCode:**

```
public class YourClassName extends AppCompatActivity{

private WebView wv_content = null;
private WebSettings webSettings = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_page);

    wv_content = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    wv_content.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv_content.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    wv_content.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    wv_content.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    wv_content.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

    wv_content.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wv_content.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    wv_content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv_content.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webSettings = wv_content.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    wv_content.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
   }
    }
```

**XML**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".WebView">


 <WebView 
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> 

<Button
  android:id="@+id/button3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="48dp"
  android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
  android:onClick="Home"
  android:text="Back"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/WebView"
  app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```